# Tempo Timesheets API for JIRA Cloud returns "Oops, you've found a dead link. - JIRA"

Tags: jira-rest-api

Our company would like to sync all time spent for each ticket within our CRM system. We are using JIRA Cloud and Tempo Timesheets plugin to manage our worklogs. Current approach:

1. Generate "Authorization" header with help of basic authorization
2. Send "GET" request following this instructions to get all worklogs - http://tempo.io/doc/timesheets/api/rest/latest/

Issues:

1. When I try to make a "GET" request with help of Postman or simply open https://our_company.atlassian.net/rest/tempo-timesheets/3/worklogs?dateFrom=2017-03-10&dateFrom=2017-03-11 it shows me 404 page
2. In addition to that, all the requests from JIRA REST API documentation work as expected

Comment: Received some response from Tempo:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Received some response from Tempo(see below):

Currently, Tempo is moving Tempo Timesheets add-on for JIRA Cloud to a new cloud technology and your instance is using it.

The new version is built on the Atlassian Connect framework, this new framework is a scalable platform for add-ons that supports rich integration with JIRA Cloud and will improve the performance and reliability of our product. 
Right now, all of our focus is on improving this new version but not all features that are available on the "old" Cloud or on Server are yet available. The API is one of these features that still need to be implemented and we estimate that this will be available some time in May.

Please take also a look at https://support.tempo.io/hc/en-us/articles/228918728-About-the-new-versions-of-Tempo-Timesheets-and-Tempo-Planner-for-Cloud for more information (the table at the bottom of the page shows the available feature and features that we will release soon).

Regards,
Susanne